# Save Arduino masterdata in database

Tags: php, arduino, esp8266

I want to save the sensor data in my database.
Therefore I want to do a GET request to a php file where I compare the uuid's. That's just to look if this arduino already exists in the database. If this Uuid does not exist than I want to do a new entry.

Have someone ideas how to realize that?

As I said before, I thought about doing a get request to the php file on my webserver but this wasn't successfull. Beceause I havent a static UUID. 
Therefore I need to hardcode it into my arduino and I also dont know how to do that.

[PHP-File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC7oe.png)
[Arduino Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuJ1Y.png)

Comment: This question seems very vague (but not so vague as to downvote).  Can you provide more information about exactly what you tried and what happened?  You say "this wasn't successful" -- what actually happened?

Comment: I have loaded up my php-File and my Arduino Code. I'm  sorry, I know that my question was a bit mixed up but I didnt know how to exactly explain my problem.
I have tried to send a request from the Arduino to the Webserver. The connection has happened but I did not get the response for the request. So I dont know if the problem is on the request or on the php file.

Answer (score 0):

cool project. 
I spot several locations where your issues could be coming from.

In your php code you expect the parameters sensorType, batteryState, onlineState, sending, frequency, sensorDateTimeId and value to be available as get parameters,yet in your arduino code, you're not sending any of those, you're only sending a uuid.

in you php code, you're using variable $uuid, yet you're not populating it anywhere.

you're trying to use mysql_real_escape_string on a array, that will lead to a error. Besides, mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated,and even removed from php in php7. you'd better use other libraries to communicate with mysql. you can for instance have a look at this tutorial: http://codular.com/php-mysqli

If you fix all of those errors, you can try your php code first, before moving on to the arduino code. you should be able to try it by just calling the php page from a browser in this way:

http://yourserver/easy2sense/phpfiles/sensor_connection.php?uuid=12345&sensorType=1&batteryState=2&onlineState=3&sending=4&frequency=5&sensorDateTimeId=6&value=7